# sys.stdout.close() running forever

Tags: python, linux, windows, logging

I want to create a file that will contain all my log messages from my Python script. Print commands, how much time each cell needs to run ect.
I use the following:

```
import logging
sys.stdout = open('my/directory' +"log.txt", 'w')

print("here is my print message"+'\n')

sys.stdout.close()
```

I'm adding this last command to check and see when my script finishes

```
print('finish!!!')
```

I tested in Windows (where I use spyder) and in Linux where I use (Jyputer)
in both environments the last cell never stops and I never get the 'finish' message. Any ideas? Or any alternatives for I need to do?
My problem is that

Comment: You shouldn't tamper with `sys.stdout`. you could use `fout = open(.....`, and then `fout.write(...` instead of `print(...`., and at the end `fout.close()`. You never get your message because you closed the file that was supposed to get it. And your script **does** finish.

Comment: @CristiFati well, the OP says that they are running the code in a Jupyter notebook, and they claim the cell never stops executing. Not sure fi that's true, but I wouldn't be surprised if tinkering with `sys.stdout` would cause some weird bug in Jupyter, which probably does all sorts of things like intercepting `sys.stdout` to redirect it.

Comment: Chrissie: why aren't you just using the `logging` module to do logging? Another alternative, use the `file` argument to `print`, so `print('hello', file=some_file_handler)` instead of messing with sys.stdout.

Comment: `print` will use `stdout` so it will never print (you closed the file). You should copy stdout and restore at the end. But it is really better not to tamper it (like other comments)

Comment: Hi Cristi, thanks for your answer. Just one clarification. I add the last print statement in order to see when the  sys.stdout.close()  finishes. I do not expect to see this message in my log file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Let's say you have this in a test.py file:

```
def print_hello():
    with open('log.txt') as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        print('hello')
```

If you run this in the command line `python test.py` you wont have any problem. But if you run this in a Jupyter notebook, you have to add stdout_obj like so:

```
stdout_obj = sys.stdout             # store original stdout 
print_hello()
sys.stdout = stdout_obj             # restore print commands to to interactive prompt
```